# Routing table ordering issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

We have our routing table set up sort of like this:

```
// ... specific routes

routes.MapRoute(
    "aspx", 
    "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This allows URLs like `/Foo.aspx` and also `/Foo` to properly route to `FooController.Index`.  I believe this was added for backwards compatibility.  However, when using `UrlHelper` to generate URLs using `UrlHelper.Action`, the uglier version of the URL is used.  For example, `Url.Action("Bar", "Foo")` yields `Foo.aspx/Bar`.

I want generated URLs to use the cleaner `Default` route.  This works if I swap the two `MapRoute` calls, but then `/Foo.aspx` no longer routes to `FooController` since the `.aspx` is seen as being included in the `{controller}` placeholder.

Is there any way in the URL parameter of `MapRoute` to enable us to place the `Default` route before the `aspx` route and allow both to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Html.RouteLink` there you gives the route name which your routing should use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx

It should work.

Comment: In keeping with this idea, you could define a second router and use that as the last parameter to the default htmlhelper?

Comment: That would work; However, I would like to find a solution where we can continue dealing with MVC action & controller names instead of having to pass the action and controller as parameters to a route instead.

Comment: @Jacob You can pass controller and action name in RouteOption as anonymous object.